# Two scripts: One changing directory other not?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have two scripts. One is :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 = 1 ]; then 
   dir=mydir-1.6_
else
    dir=mydir
fi
cd ~/code/${dir}$2
echo $(pwd)
```

The above script changes directories even though there are several posts that say that since a script is run in a sub-shell it should have no effect on the executing shell.

Now I have another script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    dir=/WORK/temp/$1
    mkdir -p $dir
    cd $dir
    wget http://somurl.com/archive.zip
    unzip archive.zip
```

The above script unzips the file in the expected directory but leaves the calling shell in the same directory. What is the difference when cd is called in both scripts?

Comment: How are you calling each script? By executing it (`scriptname`), via `bash scriptname`, via the `bash` `source` (`.`) command? What happens when you use `echo $$` before, during, and after?

Comment: This question is a general programming question not related to Ubuntu. Maybe you should ask it on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @AdrienBeau this question is perfectly on topic here

Comment: I am not using the source command. here is a demo:
`salilsurendran@salilsurendran-ThinkPad-P50:~$ myscript 1 4
/home/salilsurendran/code/mydir-1.6_4
salilsurendran@salilsurendran-ThinkPad-P50:~/code/mydir-1.6_4$ pwd
/home/salilsurendran/code/mydir-1.6_4
salilsurendran@salilsurendran-ThinkPad-P50:~/code/mydir$ myscript 2 3
/home/salilsurendran/code/mydir3
salilsurendran@salilsurendran-ThinkPad-P50:~/code/mydir3$ pwd
/home/salilsurendran/code/mydir3
salilsurendran@salilsurendran-ThinkPad-P50:~/code/mydir3$`